# Optimize Laravel Query - from 24 queries to only 1 with the collection method

Tags: php, laravel

The follow PHP laravel code in my blade file needs 24 queries into the database. Because there are 3 products and 8 months, so 8*3=24.
Can I do something to optimize the follow code with the laravel collection method to have only one query and the same results?

```
@php
    
    $products = [101 => 'product-a', 102 => 'product-b', 103 => 'product-c'];
    $from_year = 2014;
    $to_year = 2021;

    foreach ($products as $product_id => $product_title) {
        echo "<h1>$product_title</h1>";
        for ($year=$from_year;$year<=$to_year;$year++) {
            echo "<h3>$product_title</h3>";
            echo Products::getSales($product_id, $year)->count(); // 24 queries
        }
    }

@endphp
```

Comment: what does your getSales()  look like on the Product Model (looks like you may need eager/lazy loading).

Comment: Hi bro, it is a bad practice to have your logic in the blade. please stick to MVC

Comment: please provide the `getSales($product_id, $year)` method body

Answer (score 0):

you can make the `getSales()` to accept array, like here:

```
public static function getSales($products : array ,$years : array){
    return self::whereIn('id',$products)->whereIn('year',$years)->get();
}
```

and just pass it the arrays:

```
Product::getSales($products,$years);
```

but my advice is to change **this architecture**.